# Calling Java from C program

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

How to call Java methods from C program? I.e. is it possible to embed java (not necessary Sun/Oracle JVM) in other language?

Comment: This artcle:http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2001/jw-0511-legacy.html seems to talk about that.

Comment: [How to Call Java Functions from C Using JNI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CJniJava.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A full Oracle JVM is a very large chunk to pull into your existing program, but it is perfectly doable but I would recommend against it if any of the following apply:

- You need to pull a lot of data in and out of the JVM on a frequent basis.  This is expensive.
- You are not in full control of the operating system and JVM to use.
- You are not an experienced C programmer.  Debugging these things can be hard.

You might find jamvm - http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/ - an interesting alternative.  It is a very small interpreter written in C, which may be a lot easier to handle.  I have not tried embedding it.